# Is there a simple JS xhr library (for node.js) that uses Q promises for get/post actions?

Tags: ajax, node.js, get, promise, q

I'm looking for a JavaScript library that sits on top of node.js's http abstraction but returns `Q` promises (https://github.com/kriskowal/q) for `http.get()` and `http.post()` actions.

Does such thing exist?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There you go, built by Kris Kowal itself: https://github.com/kriskowal/q-io#http

Usage:

```
var http = require("q-io/http");
http.request("http://my.server.com/path").then(function() { ... });
http.read("http://my.server.com/path").then(function() { ... });
```

I haven't used this yet, and the docs are somewhat poor right now - so I can't tell you what are the args passed. But if you already know how to work with Q, than that's going to be so easy.

Note that Q-IO has many other useful functions also.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I could definitely use some help making the Q-IO docs more accessible.  The general idea is that your request can be for a URL, or it can be a JSGI request object with all the properties that implies, including a request `body`.  The response will likewise be a JSGI response object, include a response `body`. There’s more to come.

Comment: I'm glad to see a comment from you, @KrisKowal. Thanks for the reply, unfortunately I haven't used Q-IO yet, otherwise I surely would help you in these docs.